# Fade Entire Window - Then Load URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fade

I'm wondering if its possible that when a user clicks on a link, to then fade out my entire window (so maybe a div that covers the entire window, fade it to black), and then to load an external URL, like 'google'.

EG:

User clicks 'Here', entire window fades from 0% opacity, to 100% black opacity. Then, loads the link ... google.

Any ideas how I would be able to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking for the actual code for fading or loading the URL? You can load the URL using `window.location.href = "{url_to_load}";` in javascript. Load the URL after you finish animating your CSS opacity in jQuery.

Comment: Please only use this on your own special page. Doing this on a general web page just annoys people, they don't care about your effects, they just want to see the data.

Comment: Will do - this is for my portfolio, it's suppose to be fairly artistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just animate your body, then update the window's location in the "done animating" callback.

```
$("body").animate({ opacity: 0, backgroundColor: '#000' }, function() {
  window.location = "http://google.com"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this through fading out the body elements on a click function likes this:

`<a href="www.google.com" id="hyper"></a>`

```
$("#hyper").click(function(){ 
    $('body').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove();});
});
```